# About JavaScript: Can I modify the contents of a script tag after the js text contained in it is loaded and before it is executed?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, browser, greasemonkey

For example, I have a `<script> alert(1) <script>` in the web page. Now what I want to do is to change it to `<script> alert (2) <script>` after it is loaded and before it is executed, immediately. Can I succeed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is no; only by modifying the page before it is served

As you can see, you cannot intercept the script with script

It will be executed when parsed

```js
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",function() {
  document.scripts[1].textContent = "";
  alert(2)
})
```

```html
<script>alert(1)</script>
```

Here is a hack

```js
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",function() {
  alert(3)
})
```

```html
<script>// if you can insert this before you can intercept alert
const saveAlert = window.alert;
window.alert = function(str) {
  saveAlert(2)
  window.alert = saveAlert;
};
</script>
<script>alert(1)</script>
```

Proof that the other answer does not work

```js
var h = document.getElementById('hello');
h.textContent = 'alert(2)'
```

```html
<script type='text/javascript' id='hello'>
    alert(1)
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks! I got a new idea to solve the problem though I couldn't achieve my goal in the question .

Answer (score -1):

Say you set your script tag like so

```
<script type='text/javascript' id='hello'>
    alert(1)
</script>
```

Then you can get the dom element like so:

```
var h = document.getElementById('hello');
```

You can then modify the element like so:

```
h.innerHTML = 'alert(2)'
```

I would suggest also that you use something like JQuery onready to make sure that the modification code executes before the alert in the script tags.

Comment: If the alert is before the other script can be inserted, it will run before the second script. There is no way you can stop that unless you hack the alert

Comment: Make a [mcve] to prove your concept works. I don't think it does

Comment: Also it would be textContent not innerHTML if it worked at all which it does not